# Opengraph sharing in android for facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to attach an image to post with facebook through opengraph share dialog.I followed everything exactly as documentation suggested in facebook developer.I get the error "Failed to generate user preview".Should I check for publish permission ?

```
OpenGraphObject numberFriendsObject = OpenGraphObject.Factory
                .createForPost("numberfriends");
        Log.d("username:", "object type" + numberFriendsObject.getType());
        numberFriendsObject.setProperty("title", "title");
OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory
            .create(OpenGraphAction.class);
    action.setType("learn");

    action.setProperty("numberfriends", numberFriendsObject);

    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(
            SettingsScreenActivity.this, action, "numberfriends").build();

    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the permission "publish_actions" set?

EDIT:

I'm assuming you're using some sort of facebook login before this code. I utilized the facebook login button (see their docs - there's a nice tutorial):

```
    facebookLoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
```

Comment: I am new to this kind of sharing.I have not set publish_action.How to do that?

Comment: How to do without publish_actions set for open graph.It is given in doc that one need not require publish_actions sets

Comment: Not sure, but there is no downside to setting the permission. Why not just try it out?

Comment: I am not using any login button as such.can u get me a code to share image via facebook opengraph.Currently my dialog is closing after few seconds.error:failed to generate preview for user.

Comment: How are you sharing an image if you are not logging into a Facebook account?

Answer (score 0):

*As "game" is a custom property, the line*

```
    openGraphAction.setProperty("game", setObj);
```

*must be replaced by:*

```
    openGraphAction.getData().setProperty("game", setObj);
```

Reference: [Android open-graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/open-graph#apicalls-step1).

Comment: I had changed the game property to another.Still shows Failed to generate user preview.

Comment: then shorten your code like remove bitmap and other uncommon code and let it be very similar to referenced standard code. Then check what happens. You are having minor error like the one I mentioned somewhere else.